# CSS only stretch container more than the width of the page with scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I have an application that scrolls horizontally. Current I set the width of the container to 10000px and resize it based on the children using javascript.
The html looks something like this:

```
<div class=container>
  <div class="stretching-div">
    <div class="child">
    </div>
    <div class="child">
    </div>
    <div class="child">
    </div>
    <div class="child">
    </div>
    <div class="child">
    </div>
    <div class="child">
    </div>
    <div class="child">
    </div>
    <div class="child">
    </div>
    <div class="child">
    </div>
    <div class="child">
    </div>
    <div class="child">
    </div>
    <div class="child">
    </div>
    <div class="child">
    </div>
    <div class="child">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is causing me issues at the moment, because of hidden elements, etc.
So I have created a code pen to try to explain my issues in a better way:

https://codepen.io/r3plica/pen/vWrQOm

Does anyone know how I can achieve my goal without using JavaScript. Just by using CSS?

Comment: Did you try using width:100%

Comment: Hope this will help you https://codepen.io/anon/pen/POaxJa

Comment: @Sinisa, I think the point was to give `.stretching-div` the same functionality of `.fixed-width` but **without** fixing the width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [`white-space: nowrap;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) on your `.stretching-div`. Then you'll have an issue with your orange background.

> The **white-space** CSS property determines how whitespace inside an element is handled.
>
> **nowrap** Collapses whitespace as for normal, but suppresses line breaks (text wrapping) within the source.

```css
.container {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.stretching-div {
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 20px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.child {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-right: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="stretching-div">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But this can also be solved...

```css
.container {
  background-color: orange;
  border: 20px solid red;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.stretching-div {
  padding: 20px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.child {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-right: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="stretching-div">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes on your codepen and I found a solution:
https://codepen.io/ecastellano/pen/qVKQKm

The container div isn't necessary (remove it), the key here is to add these properties to the .stretching-div:

```
overflow-y: hidden;
overflow-x: auto;
white-space: nowrap;
```

Finally you'll have to remove width property to .fixed-with div and thats all :)

Hope this works for you!

Comment: That's not bad, but I need the margins to stay as they were